# Azure Synapse SQL on-demand query logs

Tags: azure-synapse, ondemand

I have a question about getting the detailed query usage logs from Azure Synapse on-demand.

With

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_external_data_processed
```

I can get the daily/weekly usage. It’s good.

But I need to get  a result like this:

[image]

in a "exportable" way (TSQL or something to query and get usage details for export needs).

I've tried to google it. But with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found it.

On each serverless DB this query gives the details:

SELECT TOP 1000 *
FROM **sys.dm_exec_requests_history**
order by start_time desc

Comment: I'm getting an error: Catalog view 'dm_exec_requests_history' is not supported. Do I need to change a setting to enable it?

Comment: With the newer versions of synapse this has changed, it is now sys.dm_pdw_exec_requests